# How to prove that Newton's Method converges with order $3$, if $f'' = 0$

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Let $f$ be a three times differentiable function and $x$ be a root s.t. $f(x) = f''(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) \ne 0$. How can we prove that Newton's method on this function converges with order $3$ in neighborhood of $x~?$

Regarding the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658748/when-is-the-order-of-convergence-of-newton-raphson-greater-than-2)

How does Taylor's expansion imply that if all derivatives of $g$ equal to $0$ until some order $p$ and pth derivative are not zero, then $g$ converges with order p.

Comment: What is $~f'(x)!=0~?$

Comment: @nmasanta I mean it is not equal to 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the order of convergence of Newton-Raphson greater than 2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658748/when-is-the-order-of-convergence-of-newton-raphson-greater-than-2)

Comment: @thisguy : command for "not equal" to is "\ne".

Comment: @CarlChristian I checked that but did not understand how g''(r) = 0 implies cubic convergence

Comment: Please state exactly what you understood of that answer and what not. Especially the 5th (large) formula should answer the question for the order of convergence. Do you understand that this formula is the Taylor expansion of $g$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I did not understand because in that answer it is stated that all derivatives of g until k is 0. However, in my question f' is not equal to 0.

Comment: But $g'(r)=0$, as explained following the 7th formula, as a consequence of $f(r)=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is there any proof that shows the order of convergence is exactly k? It is stated but I still cannot understand how.

Comment: No, the claim is or should be that the order is 3 or better.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I mean for the 3rd equation, he said that it follows from Taylor but I could not figure out how. I also could not found on the internet.

Comment: Apart from the missing factor $\frac1{k!}$, this is a Taylor expansion where all coefficients are zero and only the remainder term remains, which is written down. Perhaps you should add this point to the question, how $g'(r)=g''(r)=0$ implies $x_{n-1}-r=O((x_n-r)^3)$ per the Taylor formula.

Comment: I have added the missing factorials noted by @LutzLehmann. My thanks.

Comment: @CarlChristian can you please show me how to achieve that conclusion of Taylor's expansion? Suppose all derivatives of g are zero until an order k, with kth derivative, is not zero. Then, how does g converge to that fixed point with order k?

Comment: @CarlChristian can you check this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871351/order-of-convergence-and-taylors-formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the cited answer of Carl Christian the Newton iteration is formulated as a fixed point iteration $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$. It is shown that if $f''(r)=0$ at the root $r$, then $g'(r)=0$ from the construction of the Newton method and $g''(r)=0$ from $f''(r)=0$. It follows that
$$
|x_{n+1}-r|\le C|x_n-r|^3,
$$
where $C$ is a factor composed of $\frac16$ and an upper bound for $|g'''(x)|$ on some neighborhood of $r$ containing the iteration sequence (start the iteration close enough, or restart the iteration index if close enough to $r$ to be inside that interval). To get "pure" powers, multiply with $\sqrt{C}$ to get
$$
\sqrt{C}|x_{n+1}-r|\le (\sqrt{C}|x_n-r|)^3\implies \sqrt{C}|x_n-r|\le (\sqrt{C}|x_0-r|)^{3^n}.
$$
The last is the formula for cubic convergence.

Comment: How can you conclude the first equation? I guess I am not sure about where that 3rd power comes from.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Taylor expansion in $x=r$. $C=\frac16M_3$, $M_3=\max_{x\in I}|g'''(x)|$.