# Convergence of functions and Taylor's Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am taking a numerical analysis course and there is an exercise that is related to the order of convergence. The exercise:[image: here]

I see there is a relation between this proof and Taylor's expansion of $g$ but I cannot go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I renamed the fixed point $r$ as I am having some MathJaX problems today. I seem unable to use a "*" as a subscript today.

---

Let $\epsilon = \frac{|g^{(p)}(r)|}{2}>0$. Then by the continuity of $g^{(p)}$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$ |r - x| < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |g^{(p)}(r) - g^{(p)}(x)| < \epsilon.$$
It follows that $|g^{(p)}(x)| \geq \epsilon >0 $ for all $x \in (r-\delta,r+\delta)$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Then by Taylor's formula there exists at least one $\xi$ between $r$ and $x$ such that $$g(x) - g(r) = \frac{1}{p!} g^{(p)}(\xi)(x-r)^p.$$
If we choose $x \in (r-\delta,r+\delta)$, then we are certain that $g^{(p)}(\xi) \not =0$. If we also choose $x \not = r$, then we are certain that $g(x) \not = g(r) = r$.

Now let $M \geq 0$ be given by
$$ M = \sup \{ |g^{(p)}(x)| \: : \: x \in [r-\delta,r+\delta] \}.$$
It is straight forward to verify that $M \geq \epsilon$, but this is not important here.
Now choose $\delta_1>0$ such that $$L = \frac{M}{p!} \delta_1^{p-1} < 1,$$
and set $\delta_2 = \frac{1}{2} \min\{\delta, \delta_1\}$. If we choose $x \in [r-\delta_2,r+\delta_2]$ then
$$ |g(x) - g(r)| \leq L |x-r|.$$ This completes the preparations.

Let now $0<|r-x_0| \leq \delta_2$ and let $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ for all $n$. By induction, we have $$\forall n \: : \: \left( x_n \in [r-\delta,r+\delta] \: \wedge \: x_n \not = r\right).$$ Moreover, we have at least one $\xi_n$ between $r$ and $x_n$ such that
$$ \frac{x_n-r}{(x_n-r)^p} = \frac{g^{(p)}(\xi_n)}{p!}$$
The functional iteration is converging at least linearly because $$|x_{n}-r| \leq L^n |x_0 - r|.$$ Since $\xi_n$ is between $x_n$ and $r$ the squeeze lemma will imply that $\xi_n \rightarrow r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. It follows that $$\frac{x_n-r}{(x_n-r)^p} \rightarrow \frac{g^{(p)}(r)}{p!} \not = 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
This shows that the order of convergence is exactly $p$ and the proof is complete.